# Integrating docker with gitlab-ci - how does the docker image get built and used?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I was previously using the shell for my gitlab runner to build my project. So far I have set up the pipeline that will run whatever commands I have set in the gitlab-ci.yml file seen below:

**gitlab-ci.yml using shell runner**

```
before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - dev
  - staging
  - production

build_dev:
  stage: dev

  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm run build 
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --browsers PhantomJS --watch false
```

Now, I want to switch to a docker image. I have reconfigured the runner to use a docker image, and I specified the image in my new gitlab-ci.yml file seen below. I followed the gitlab-ci docker tutorial and this is where it left off so I'm not entirely sure where to go from here:

**gitlab-ci.yml using docker runner**

```
image: node:8.10.0

before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - dev
  - staging
  - production

build_dev:
  stage: dev

  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm run build 
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --browsers PhantomJS --watch false
```

**Questions:**

1. With my current gitlab-ci.yml file, how does this build a docker image/does it even build one? If it does, what does that mean? Currently the pipeline passed, but I have no idea if it did in a docker image or not (am I supposed to be able to tell?).

   Also, let's say the docker image was created, ran the tests, and the pipeline passed; it should push the code to a new repository (not included in yml file yet). From what I gathered, the image isn't being pushed, it's just the code, right? So what do I do with this created docker image?
2. How does the Dockerfile get used? I see no link between the gitlab-ci.yml file and Dockerfile.
3. Do I need to surround all commands in the gitlab-ci.yml file in `docker run <commands>` or `docker exec <commands>`? Without including one of these 2 commands, it seems like it would just run on the server and not in a docker image.
4. I've seen people specify an image in both the gitlab-ci.yml file and Dockerfile. I have an angular project, and I specified an image of `image: node:8.10.0`. In the Dockerfile, should I specify the same image? I've seen some projects where they are completely different and I'm wondering what the use of both images are/if picking one image over another will severely impact my builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take a different approach on building your app if you want to fully dockerize it. Export angular things into Dockerfile and get docker operations inside your `.gitlab-ci` instead of angular stuff like here:

```
stages:
  - build
#  - release
#  - deploy

.build_template: &build_definition
  stage: build
  image: docker:17.06
  services:
    - docker:17.06-dind
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE -f $DOCKERFILE ./
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE

build_app_job:
  <<: *build_definition
  variables:
    CONTAINER_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app:latest
    DOCKERFILE: ./Dockerfile.app

build_nginx_job:
  <<: *build_definition
  variables:
    CONTAINER_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/nginx:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/nginx:latest
    DOCKERFILE: ./Dockerfile
```

You can set up a few build jobs - for production, development, staging etc.
Right next to your `.gitlab-ci.yaml` you can put `Dockerfile` and `Dockerfile.app` - Dockerfile.app stands for building you angular app:

```
FROM node:10.5.0-stretch
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/remote
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
# do your commands here
```

Now with your app built, it can be served via a web server - it's your choice and a different configuration that follows with each choice - cant even scratch a surface here. That'd be implemented in `Dockerfile` - we usually use Nginx in our company.

From here on it's about releasing your images and deploying them. I've only specified how to build them in docker as it seems this is what the question is about.

If you want to deploy your image and run it somewhere - choose a provider - AWS, Heroku, own infrastructure - have it your way, but this is far too much to cover all those in a single answer so I'll leave it for another question when you specify where'd you like to deploy your newly built images and how would you like to serve it. In our company, we orchestrate things with Rancher, but there are multiple awesome and competing options in the market.

---

**Edit** for a custom registry

The above `.gitlab-ci` configuration works with Gitlab's "internal" registry only, in case you want to utilize your own registry, change the values accordingly:

```
#previous configs
script:
        - docker login -u mysecretlogin -p mysecretpasswd registry.local.com
        # further configs
```

- from `-u gitlab-ci-token` to your login in the registry,
- from `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` to your password
- from `$CI_REGISTRY` to your registry address

Those values should be stored in Gitlab's `CI secret variables` and referenced via env variables so that they are not saved in the repository.

Finally, your script might look like below in case you decided to protect these values. Refer to Gitlab's [official docs on how to add secret CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables) - super easy task.

```
#previous configs
script:
        - docker login -u $registrylogin -p $registrypasswd $registryaddress
        # further configs
```

Comment: After a lot of trying and going through another tutorial, I ran into the issue of running this command: `- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY`. It recommends I use `--password-stdin` but the only ways to use this were piping in the password from a file like so: 

`cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin`. Is there a way to use encrypted passwords through gitlabs "secret variables" section?

Comment: just for clarification - you are not using gitlab's registry?

Comment: After I asked the question I set up my own local registry.

Comment: So when I run this command it's saying: `$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
"docker login" requires at most 1 argument.`

Comment: The above method works with gitlab's registry only, in case you want to utilize your own registry, change the values accordingly from `gitlab-ci-token` to your login in the registry, `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` to your password and `$CI_REGISTRY` to your registry public address - they should be stored in gitlab's secrets and referenced via env variables so that they are not saved in the repository. I can make a update with it if it's unclear.

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-docker-images-and-host-a-docker-image-repository-with-gitlab. I set it up and it's connected to my gitlab. I'm hosting gitlab on a local server here.

Comment: I've updated the answer with detailed information on how to reconfigure the `.gitlab-ci` we wrote before so that it references your custom registry.

Comment: I tried this: `docker login -u $USERNAME --password-stdin $PASSWORD http://my.gitlab.ip:4444` and receive this error: `"docker login" requires at most 1 argument.` Using -p tells me to use --password-stdin

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it answered my original question, my followup question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211323/docker-login-using-p-gives-error-and-when-i-switch-to-password-stdin-like-it