# docker login using -p gives error, and when I switch to --password-stdin like it recommends still gives error - gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a docker registry setup on my gitlab server. Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:18.05.0-ce

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

variables:
  TEST_IMAGE: http://my.gitlab.ip:4444/path/to/project:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  RELEASE_IMAGE: http://my.gitlab.ip:4444/path/to/project:latest

before_script:
  - docker login -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD http://my.gitlab.ip:4444

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $TEST_IMAGE

# ...

# more commands
```

I am using a secret variable for my username and password. When I push code and the runner runs through this file, I get the following error:

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://my.gitlab.ip:4444/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

So I tried using `--password-stdin` instead like this:

- docker login -u $USERNAME --password-stdin $PASSWORD http://my.gitlab.ip:4444

And I get this error:

```
"docker login" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker login --help'.

Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER] [flags]
```

**Edit:**

I have also tried this for my docker login command:

```
docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

and received this error:

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://my.gitlab.ip:4444/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

I have made the following changes on my gitlab server:

In /etc/default/docker:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry http://my.gitlab.ip:4444"
```

In /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : ["http://my.gitlab.ip:4444"]
}
```

I have also done the same on my gitlab runner (different server).

Why is it showing that I'm using https in the error and how do I change it to http?

Comment: Please specify a image tag for the docker you are using with those builds- using the latest (as you do now) is never a good/stable practice - docker versions might change how it behaves. I have it running properly on `docker:17.06`

Comment: I just did. Also I added a bit more info to my Edit section

Comment: Then it actually forbids it. Found a GitLab issue for it - fortunately or not - you will have to secure your registry, [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1842) or use an already secured registry elsewhere. It's easy to set up a secure registry - it only requires a public IP for the server and a registered domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure when you set this up, but there is an updated permission model after `GitLab 8.12` when using GitLab runners and logging into the GitLab Container registry.

As [per the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#container-registry), you can do:

```
before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

Comment: Please take a look at my question again, I added information to the edit section

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already resolved your issue, but while searching for the difference of the login options (and best practises) I noticed your error is actually not even about that, is it?

The error we see is the following:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://my.gitlab.ip:4444/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

but in your .gitlab-ci.yml file you list `https://my.gitlab.ip:4444/v2/` as your URL. While this doesn't have to be related, it seems to me that ssl is missing somewhere, e.g. http vs https.

Answer (score 0):

According to [gitlab docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#examples) --password-stdin is a flag not a command line variable. In the example provided the password was being read from a file not directly through command line.